# How to use custom date with apache CXF for generating the right WSDL, using only annotation

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I am using custom Date from org.threeten.bp library, but it whould be the same with Joda Time or I guess Java8 times.

I was able to develop my Webservices using custom date form Threeten modules, using JAXB adapters to marshall from/to LocalDate types.

Here is my problem, the webservice works really well using soapui or other programs, **but** the exposed WSDL gives me a String type instead of a dateTime

```
<xs:complexType name="MyDTO">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="testDate" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="code" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:/sequence>
<xs:/complexType>
```

i was expecting **type="xs:dateTime"** for my date but i get instead
**type="xs:string"**

The Object:

```
public class MyDTO implements Serializable {
    public LocalDateTime testDate;
    public String code;
}
```

What I try is using annotations at package-info.java level:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaTypes({ 
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime", type = org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.class),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime", type = org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.class),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime", type = org.threeten.bp.LocalTime.class) })
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = LocalDate.class, value = LocalDateXmlAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = LocalTime.class, value = LocalTimeXmlAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = LocalDateTime.class, value = LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)})
package mypackage.dto;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalTime;

import com.migesok.jaxb.adapter.javatime.LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter;
import com.migesok.jaxb.adapter.javatime.LocalDateXmlAdapter;
import com.migesok.jaxb.adapter.javatime.LocalTimeXmlAdapter;
```

My adapters are here: https://github.com/pdemanget/jaxb-threeten-adapters

They convert from LocalDate to String, i would like to avoid using java.util.Date at all.

I have about 300 classes to manage so changing type to each objects, or give a specific annotation is not what I want to do.

I try anyway some different options

using annotation at **field** level

```
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
 public LocalDateTime testDate;
  //it works well on field, but not on package level and i would have 300classes to modify
```

Using annotation at **class** level

```
 @XmlType(name = "dateTime", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
 class LocalDateTime
 //It works well on Class, bu not on package level, and I would have to patch the library I use, This is rally impossible.
```

Using annotation at **package** level with  `@XmlSchemaTypes` : The solution i have choosen, is allowed on package level, but it doesnt works at all, it seem to be overloaded by the adapters usage with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters`.

I also found some XML base solution, but i want to use annotation, will it be possible?